# Building a data frame from a list of lists of lists

Tags: data, dataset

OK, let's say we have a following list of lists of lists:

```
{{{4, 2}, {6, 2}, {2, 2}}, {{6, 3}, {4, 1}, {3, 1}, {2, 1}},      
{{6,2}, {3, 2}, {4, 1}, {1, 1}}, {{4, 2}, {1, 2}, {6, 1}, {3, 1}}, 
{{4,3}, {6, 1}, {1, 1}, {2, 1}}, {{5, 3}, {1, 1}, {2, 1}, {3,1}}, 
{{2, 2}, {5, 2}, {6, 1}, {3, 1}}, {{1, 2}, {5, 2}, {3, 2}}, 
{{6, 2}, {3, 2}, {2, 1}, {5, 1}}, {{3, 3}, {6, 1}, {1, 1}, {5,1}}, 
{{5, 2}, {2, 2}, {4, 1}, {1, 1}}, {{2, 3}, {4, 1}, {6, 1}, {5, 1}}, 
{{1, 3}, {4, 1}, {3, 1}, {5, 1}}, {{4, 2}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}, {5, 1}}}
```

Now from such list, call it `L` for convenience, I'd like to create a data frame where there are `Length[L]` rows (so 14 rows in this case; that number is known in advance btw). Now, columns. I would like to have `Length[Range[min,max,1]]` columns labeled by `Range[min,max,1]` where

```
min = Min[Map[Min,Map[Min,L,{2}],{1}]]
```

and

```
max = Max[Map[Max,Map[Max,L,{2}],{1}]]
```

so for the case above we'd have `min=1` and `max=6` and so we'd have 6 columns, labelled by `1`,`2`,`3`,`4`,`5` and `6`. I hope that's clear. Now the entries of the data frame. So if we look at the first list of `L`: `{{4,2},{6,2},{2,2}}`.That corresponds to the first row of the data frame. Now `{{4,2},{6,2},{2,2}}`tells us that we would 2 in the 4th column, 2 in the 6th column, 2 in the 2nd column. Also, we would like to have 0's elsewhere, so we'd have 0's in the 1st,3rd and 5th column of the first row. The main objective is to then transfer it to R and do the analysis there. I'd really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SparseArray` as follows:

```
sa = SparseArray[Join @@ MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], #[[1]]} -> #[[2]] &, L, {2}]];

TeXForm@MatrixForm[sa]
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccccc}
>  0 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 2 \\
>  0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 3 \\
>  1 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 2 \\
>  2 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 1 \\
>  1 & 1 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 1 \\
>  1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 3 & 0 \\
>  0 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 1 \\
>  2 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
>  0 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
>  1 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
>  1 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\
>  0 & 3 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
>  3 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
>  2 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

```
TableForm[sa, TableHeadings -> {Range[Length@sa], Range[Length[sa[[1]]]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: This is great, thank you so much @kglr. I can't really figure out how does your `sa` function or perhaps `MapIndexed` part of it , "creates" the correct row number?

Comment: @amator2357, In `MapIndexed` the slot `#2` is a pair that refers to `{rowindex, columnindex}` and its first part (`#2[[1]]`) is the row index.

Comment: Thank you @kglr. I understood that, I wasn't sure how was the `#2[[1]]` spitting out the correct row index, but I see it now. Thanks again for your help, much appreciated.